# boost::filesystem::path to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, file, boost

How can I convert file that is represented as boost::filesystem::path to an object of type QByteArray? I need to create MD5 hash from file data, and QCryptographicHash::hash needs QByteArray as first parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [path::string()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/filesystem/doc/path.htm#string) method.

So the code would look like this:

```
const QByteArray pathAsArray = QByteArray(path.string().c_str());
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary in this case pass string size to QByteArray as second param?

Comment: It's optional for null-terminated strings, as "If size is negative, data is assumed to point to a nul-terminated string and its length is determined dynamically. The terminating nul-character is not considered part of the byte array." http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-2